# Network / Internet diagnostic tool to locate an error?

Tags: networking, internet, monitoring, diagnostic

I’m facing some difficulties with the Internet / network at my work and I have trouble locating the precise error and when and how it occurs. The problem is that the client machines in the house sporadic  is disconnected to the Internet.

I’m some what new so I haven’t that much inside in the network and apparently neither has my predecessor. What I am requesting and hoping you guys knows about is, if there exist some kind of network monitor tool I can install and run and it will periodically check the network, the Internet connection etc. and record to logs. Then, if there suddenly arises a problem some time of the day in some part of the network or the Internet connection, I can check it perhaps the next day.

I’ve just downloaded and installed Microsoft Network Monitor 3.3 application and hopeful it can give me some answers on where the instability is located but I still would like a tool to make different checks and test in some time interval.

Do anyone know about such a program or another kind of performance / diagnostic tool / method I can use?

Sincere
Jesper

Comment: From your question I could assume you have to deal with Windows, but it'll be good if you would have the OS name stated explicitly as tag.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ping plotter http://www.pingplotter.com/ and http://www.nessoft.com/multiping/ can be used for this.

set up pings against all you nodes in the web\lan and get a detailed graph bases on how you configure it.